# QGIS 3.10 install on Ubuntu 18.04 will not recognize any projections

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ubuntu

As the the title states a clean install of QGIS 3.10 on ubuntu simply will not recognize any projections and sets all data (both raster and vector) to unknown projections. This issue even extends to the popular quickmap service plugin.

I have tried numerous different methods of installing and each one has this issue and I simply can not figure out why as QGIS on my laptop running ubuntu does not have this issue.

The about page:

[image]

Comment: Show your versions about QGIS, GDAL and Proj in the About dialog.

Comment: Added a link for the about dialog.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running QGis 3.10.2 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

```
QGIS version 3.10.2-A Coruña
QGIS code revision 616ad4531b
Compiled against Qt 5.9.5
Running against Qt 5.9.5
Compiled against GDAL/OGR 2.2.3
Running against GDAL/OGR 2.2.3
Compiled against GEOS 3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2
Running against GEOS 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
Compiled against SQLite 3.22.0
Running against SQLite 3.22.0
PostgreSQL Client Version 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
SpatiaLite Version 4.3.0a
QWT Version 6.1.3
QScintilla2 Version 2.10.2
PROJ.4 Version 493
OS Version Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
```

and all is fine. So I think your versions of gdal and proj look ok, it might be a permissions issue?

My entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
deb https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
deb-src https://qgis.org/ubuntu bionic main # disabled on upgrade to bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

This smells like GDAL and proj installation/versioning issues.

QGIS uses GDAL/OGR to input and output many types of layers, and the proj library to handle projections.

QGIS version 3.10 transitioned to proj version 6.x. This has been a major change, with glitches appearing and being fixed in various point releases of QGIS, GDAL, and proj released in a coordinated fashion in recent weeks. Woe betide you if your versions are not fully up to date, or if installation has munged something.

1. In the About... dialog for QGIS, make sure you are running QGIS 3.10.2, GDAL >= 3.0.4, and proj >= 6.3.0.
2. Then, from the QGIS Browser, open a Terminal in your project home directory and try running `gdal-config --version` and `projinfo` to make sure that the same versions are default binaries on your system, and that they are accessible.
3. Finally, check whether the setting of the environment variable `PROJ_LIB` is pointing to your `share/proj`.

I *believe* but am not 100% sure that that 2 and 3 are actually unnecessary, since QGIS should be running its own required binaries and `proj` version 6+ looks in the right places in addition to `PROJ_LIB`. However, if either of these, or of course 1, are wrong, it would be a symptom of an installation problem to resolve properly.

**Editing to add:** Seems the right GDAL and PROJ will be part of Ubuntu 20.04, see http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Good-news-next-Ubuntu-version-shipping-with-gdal3-proj6-tt5428920.html

Comment: GDAL is currently 2.2.3 so I will try to fix that and hopefully it will solve the issue

Comment: I ended up installing QGIS with flatpak because dependency errors kept popping up when trying to reinstall otherwise regardless of the repository. The flatpak installation while not the most ideal is working perfectly.

Comment: Just saw this on the dev mailing list, so known issue: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/QGIS-Developer-Good-news-next-Ubuntu-version-shipping-with-gdal3-proj6-tt5428920.html
Edited answer to add this.